# Merging two functions for a toggle button

Tags: jquery

I have two similar functions performing a similar task, but I'm not quite sure how to best merge them as I'm still a beginner...

fiddle shows the two functions:
https://jsfiddle.net/umda6wn6/1/

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="green button">
    <b>Button</b>
  </div>
  <div class="red button">
    <b>Button</b>
  </div>
  <div class="green gdiv">
    GREENGREENGREENGREEN
  </div>
  <div class="green gdiv">
    GREENGREENGREENGREEN
  </div>
  <div class="red rdiv">
    REDREDREDRED
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonoff {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".green").click(function() {
    $(".gdiv").toggle();
    $(".green").toggleClass("buttonoff");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".red").click(function() {
    $(".rdiv").toggle();
    $(".red").toggleClass("buttonoff");
  });
});
```

I guess it would look somewhat like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(???).toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("buttonoff");
  });
```

But I don't know what to put inside '???'. As I'm going to add more buttons, I'd like a way to expand this without having to add another function for every new one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know which button was clicked, you can check out its classes this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
      //get classes of element as array
      //    index 0 would be red or green
      var classes = $( this ).prop('className').split(' ');
      //    get first letter of red/ green
      var firstletter = classes[0].substr( 0, 1 );
      $("." + firstletter + "div").toggle();
      $( "." + classes[0] ).toggleClass("buttonoff");
  });
});
```

Test it here https://jsfiddle.net/8sbe48oa/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple method which gets called from the click event. Inside the click event function the keyword `this` will refer to the element which was clicked. I noticed you are referencing the same element using two different class selectors. To simplify you could set the click event passing in toggleBtn function from the example below and it will call `jQuery.toggle` and `jQuery.toggleClass` on the same element as it was doing before from your example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function toggleBtn() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggle();
        $this.toggleClass("buttonoff");
    }

    $(".gdiv").click(toggleBtn);
});
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: this won't toggle gdiv?

Comment: In your example there is a div with 2 classes `green` and `gdiv` and some JS code `$(".rdiv").toggle(); $(".red").toggleClass("buttonoff");`. From what I can see it is referencing the same element so there is no need to reference both classes. E.g. green is same as gdiv since the classes are on the same element.

Comment: I was not clear on what you were attempting to achieve. After playing with the example you provided I became aware of my confusion. @KIMB-technologies has the correct answer, however, I would recommend avoiding JS code logic reliance on class names where possible.